# Output copied twice in Nim game in Java

Tags: java

Im learning java with "programmingbydoing" and i have a problem with Nim game, everything works fine apart from one thing, which is that both:

```
"System.out.print(n1 + ", choose a pile: ");"
```

and

```
"System.out.print(n2 + ", choose a pile: ");"
```

is out printed twice after the first time.

Here is code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Player one, enter your name: ");
        String n1 = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Player two, enter your name: ");
        String n2 = input.nextLine();

        int a = 3;
        int b = 4;
        int c = 5;
        int count = 1;

        System.out.println("A: "+a+" B: "+b+" C: "+c);

        nim_loop:while(a > 0 || b > 0 || c > 0) {

            while(count % 2 != 0 ) {
                System.out.print(n1+", choose a pile: ");
                String first = input.nextLine();

                if (first.contains("a") || first.contains("A")) {
                    System.out.print("How many to remove from pile " + first + "? ");
                    int second = input.nextInt();
                    count = count + 1;

                    a = a - second;

                    System.out.println("A: " + a + " B: " + b + " C: " + c);

                    if(a <= 0 && b <= 0 && c <= 0){
                        break nim_loop;
                    }

                }
                else if (first.contains("b") || first.contains("B")) {
                    System.out.print("How many to remove from pile " + first + "? ");
                    int second = input.nextInt();
                    count = count + 1;

                    b = b - second;

                    System.out.println("A: " + a + " B: " + b + " C: " + c);

                    if(a <= 0 && b <= 0 && c <= 0){
                        break nim_loop;
                    }
                }
                else if (first.contains("c") || first.contains("C")) {
                    System.out.print("How many to remove from pile " + first + "? ");
                    int second = input.nextInt();
                    count = count + 1;

                    c = c - second;

                    System.out.println("A: " + a + " B: " + b + " C: " + c);

                    if(a <= 0 && b <= 0 && c <= 0){
                        break nim_loop;
                    }

                }
            }

            while(count % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print(n2 + ", choose a pile: ");

                String third = input.nextLine();

                if (third.contains("a") || third.contains("A")) {
                    System.out.print("How many to remove from pile " + third + "? ");
                    int fourth = input.nextInt();
                    count = count + 1;

                    a = a - fourth;

                    System.out.println("A: " + a + " B: " + b + " C: " + c);
                } else if (third.contains("b") || third.contains("B")) {
                    System.out.print("How many to remove from pile " + third + "? ");
                    int fourth = input.nextInt();
                    count = count + 1;

                    b = b - fourth;

                    System.out.println("A: " + a + " B: " + b + " C: " + c);
                } else if (third.contains("c") || third.contains("C")) {
                    System.out.print("How many to remove from pile " + third + "? ");
                    int fourth = input.nextInt();
                    count = count + 1;

                    c = c - fourth;

                    System.out.println("A: " + a + " B: " + b + " C: " + c);
                }
            }

        }

        if (count % 2 != 0) {

            System.out.println("Game ended, Player " + n1 + " is a winner.");
        } else if (count % 2 == 0){
            System.out.println("Game ended, Player " + n2 + " is a winner.");
        } 
    }
}
```

And here are the pictures of what happens when i run it:

[image: What happens]

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program?

Comment: If you have not yet learned to use a debugger (a) consider learning it (b) until you learn, you may put in extra `System.out.println()` calls that can tell you which parts of the code are executed and how many times.

Comment: Ok thanks I think I will learn debugging then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the first if condition in first inner loop is true and when you get the user input by using `nextInt()` it only reads the `int` value and does not consume the last new line character i,e `\n`. So the subsequent call to `nextLine()` will be skipped i,e the `nextLine()` call in second inner while loop will be skipped without any value but `System.out.print(n2 + ", choose a pile: ");` will be printed as it is before `nextLine()` call and control goes back to outer while loop.

Now the `count` value is 2 so first inner while condition will be false and control goes to second inner while loop. And again it prints `b, choose a pile:`. Hope this clears your question

Workaround is fire a blank `nextLine()` call after every `nextInt()` or use `nextLine()` inside if condition and parse the user input using `Integer.parseInt(String)` method.

Example code :

```
if (first.contains("a") || first.contains("A")) {
  System.out.print("How many to remove from pile " + first + "? ");
  int second = input.nextInt();
  input.nextLine(); // firing an blank nextLine call
  count = count + 1;
  a = a - second;
  System.out.println("A: " + a + " B: " + b + " C: " + c);

  if(a <= 0 && b <= 0 && c <= 0){
     break nim_loop;
  }
```

For more information - [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Comment: Yea i know, the condition "if(a <= 0 && b <= 0 && c <= 0)" will be false, it's good that it doesnt break when only one value is 0 (a in this case), becouse the game is suppose to end only when all three values a, b and c reach 0 or less. My question is when it enters next inner loop and prints out "b, choose a pile:" , why does it print it twice?

Comment: @Biafra I have updated the answer, it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank You, Im not sure i understand why i have to do this but it works :). Will check out that link You provided to find out. Thanks

Comment: @Biafra Okay, What is happening is that the call to `nextLine()` in second while loop first finishes the line where the user enters  `How many to remove from pile ` this is because `nextInt()` reads only one int and does not finish that particular line. 
This is the behavior of `Scanner`, you can read more about Scanner here - [Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: Ok after reading it again i finally understand it, i have to say You explaned it very well:)

Comment: @Biafra Glad that you understood.